# JSP name parameter dynamically displaying in the same JSP page as string

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I need to display the value entered in the first `input type = text` as a `String` using `out.println()` within the same JSP dynamically, now I am able to display the text entered in the first text field into an another i.e., the second text field.

```html
<html> 
<body>
    <script>
    function jspFunction()
    {
        var dat = document.getElementById("dateId").value;
        document.getElementById("dateId1").value = dat;
    }
    </script>

<p>Input text : <input type="text" name="dateName" id="dateId" size="30" onchange="jspFunction()"/></p>
<p>Output text area : <input type="text" name="dateName1" id="dateId1"/></p> // I am getting proper o/p here

<%
String ss = request.getParameter("dateName1");
out.println("Converted to string   :" + ss); // The string value is displaying as null
%>

</body>
</html>
```

I need the `String ss` value dynamically changed and displayed automatically below the o/p of html text tag field.

I am not sure if `String ss = request.getParameter("dateName1");` is even receiving the value.

Comment: It is important to know that jsp code executes on the server.  If you want it to execute you have to post a form back to the server.  Javascript might be the better tool in this case if all you want is the value of an input displayed elsewhere on the same page.

Comment: request.getParameter will always be null .You should use js as siad above or should submit form and set parameter there.

Comment: this will be done easily by using ajax :)

Answer (score 2):

[jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) code executes on the server side. If you know the basic concept than a JSP is converted into a Java class ([servlet](/questions/tagged/servlet)) and that servlet generates HTML which is what you see in the browser.

So when you try to load the JSP in the browser then the code between `<% ... %>` is converted to java then to HTML by the container and then rendered in the browser. So if you check the HTML source in the browser (right-click on page → view source) you would see the code between `<% ... %>` is no where to be seen.

While Javascript is a client-side (browser) language as opposed to JSP, so if you want to do some dynamic stuff on the page, then here is a sample:

```html
<html> 
<body>
    <script>
    function jspFunction()
    {
        var dat = document.getElementById("dateId").value;
        document.getElementById("dateId1").value = dat;

        // here is the change
        document.getElementById("print-here").innerHTML = dat;
    }
    </script>

<p>Input text : <input type="text" name="dateName" id="dateId" size="30" onchange="jspFunction()"/></p>
<p>Output text area : <input type="text" name="dateName1" id="dateId1"/></p> // I am getting proper o/p here

<div id="print-here">
<!-- And here is the div where the value would be printed -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Or else you can use [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) to send a request to the server and then read the response to print the value.

Or else you can use [html-form](/questions/tagged/html-form) and use a submit button to submit the value of the field and then read it through `request.getParameter("dateName1");` when the page is refreshed.

<sub>**Note:** I have used the tags in answer which provide good basic tutorial and information about each technology. I highly recommend going through the concepts. Thanks</sub>

Comment: What i actually need to do is dynamically compare the string value entered in the text area in this JSP with an String values In an another JSP i have included the first JSP in the second JSP using '<@include>' so these both JSP will be displayed in the same page . I am planing to compare the values from these jsp's using somethin like 'if(request.getAttribute(print-here).equals(another_value))' but the "print-here" in this code i a not able to use it as a string.

Comment: Comparing in JSP is as the same as comparing in a Java class's (servlet) method. So when you enter something in the textfield you have to send the data to the server either through ajax or through submitting the HTML form to the same JSP and when the JSP reloads it would have the value in request parameter and then you can compare. Try to understand that JSP is not HTML. HTML is shown in the browser and JSP runs on server and generates HTML.

Answer (score 0):

JSP code is running on server side and JavaScript is running on client side(browser).

So if you need to connect these to to each other dynamically without refreshing the whole page you should use AJAX for sure.

Remember that you should do this if you want to check on the value that is entered in the textbox in server side for some reason otherwise JavaScript is all you need.